# Enabling SSL/TLS support in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, webserver

I have enabled SSL support in SpringBoot by giving the below properties in application.properties and it is working fine

```
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12 
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
```

but I don't what values should provide for the below properties

```
server.ssl.ciphers 
server.ssl.protocol
server.ssl.enabled-protocols
```

I want to use strong ciphers/protocols so that my application is not vulnerable to attacks.

Also what are their default values in case I do not specify them in application.properties?

I am using Java 1.8 and SpringBoot version 1.5.3 and Undertow as web server

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the properties provided in the Docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.html

There are nested specific properties for undertow and tomcat which you can use to set ssl properties.

The following property sets to default `private String protocol = "TLS";`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
public class ServerProperties
        implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer, EnvironmentAware, Ordered {

    /**
     * Server HTTP port.
     */
    private Integer port;

    /**
     * Network address to which the server should bind to.
     */
    private InetAddress address;

    /**
     * Context path of the application.
     */
    private String contextPath;

    /**
     * Display name of the application.
     */
    private String displayName = "application";

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ErrorProperties error = new ErrorProperties();

    /**
     * Path of the main dispatcher servlet.
     */
    private String servletPath = "/";

    /**
     * ServletContext parameters.
     */
    private final Map<String, String> contextParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    /**
     * If X-Forwarded-* headers should be applied to the HttpRequest.
     */
    private Boolean useForwardHeaders;

    /**
     * Value to use for the Server response header (no header is sent if empty).
     */
    private String serverHeader;

    /**
     * Maximum size in bytes of the HTTP message header.
     */
    private int maxHttpHeaderSize = 0; // bytes

    /**
     * Maximum size in bytes of the HTTP post content.
     */
    private int maxHttpPostSize = 0; // bytes

    /**
     * Time in milliseconds that connectors will wait for another HTTP request before
     * closing the connection. When not set, the connector's container-specific default
     * will be used. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.
     */
    private Integer connectionTimeout;

    private Session session = new Session();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Ssl ssl;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Compression compression = new Compression();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private JspServlet jspServlet;

    private final Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    private final Jetty jetty = new Jetty();

    private final Undertow undertow = new Undertow();

    private Environment environment;


}
```

Comment: But what values should I specify as ciphers?

Comment: yes it accepts array of  string like server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256

Comment: so which ciphers should I keep in the above list?

Comment: Based on the algorithm you choose for ssl settings. Accordingly you can set it

Comment: I am using RSA algorithm for generating the keystore using keytool